# Mediawiki update script

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I inherited an old (version 1.4) Mediawiki installation. I'd like to update it, but have had a lot of trouble doing so.

I downloaded Mediawiki 1.19 and put it in a new directory. I put the old LocalSettings.php file in this new directory, altering only the $wgScriptPath variable to reflect the new directory name. I didn't alter the database name, user, or password.

When I try to run the **`update.php`** script, I get this:

DB connection error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket `'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) (localhost)`.

I've googled this pretty extensively. It's a common enough error, but most of the solutions involve cases where MySQL wasn't running in the first place or where something about the socket needs to be changed at a global level (i.e., for the whole site). Neither of these cases can apply, since there is a lot of other MySQL stuff going on with the site that is working fine.

On the off chance that something was wrong with the user credentials, I tried creating a completely new user and adding that user to LocalSettings.php, but I still get the same error.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about the MySQL error you are seeing specifically but there is an [upgrade1_5.php script](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/core.git;a=blob;f=maintenance/upgrade1_5.php) in the maintenance directory for upgrading 1.4 -> 1.5. You might want to see if running that first helps.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. Good idea, but using this script still gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my initial download of Mediawiki 1.19 was somehow corrupt or incomplete. I re-downloaded the software and everything worked fine.